# App Engine Email Feedback Loop Notifications

Tags: google-app-engine, email

Top email APIs (like Sendgrid and Amazon SES) notify applications when an email bounces or is marked as spam. They know when an email is marked as spam through email feedback loop agreements with major email client providers.

App Engine notifies applications when an email bounces back. But is there a way to know if an email was marked as spam? Do those bounce notifications cover spam reports as well? The documentation does not include a lot of details about the type of notifications we get (soft bounces, hard bounces, spam reports, ...etc.).

Can anyone shed some light or offer suggestions?